# how to change a background color of ubuntu terminal by default

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I have configured my Ubuntu to use remote desktop. 
Then, remote desktop worked properly. 
After connection, a problem appeared.

Ubuntu terminal background color was changed from purple to white
and some icons were broken.
I think it's not the problem of changing color, so I want to use my Ubuntu by default setting, not changing color manually.

Please, help me recover this problem.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 you can change background doing this
1. Open the Terminal
2. Edit -> Preferences
Opens the window
3. Unnamed -> Colors and select color
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit profile in terminal > then edit > go to colour and then select the colour from built in scheme under linux console

Comment: I tried this in your way, but terminal background is same

Answer (score 0):

try 
`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

Search for Tweak Tool in Unity Dash, open it, go into Icons and select Restore Defaults.

Comment: Thank you, icon has been restored :)

Comment: Pleasure... By the way [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is a great community and helped me a lot when ever karma hits my ubuntu ;) .